# How to calculate the limits for volume and mass for induction heating samples?

Tags: thermodynamics, induction

I'm evaluating the feasibility of using volumetric induction heating to quickly heat up steel molds. One thing I have come across is that induction heating really only works for surface heating or for 'small' volumes, without really specifying how big or massive my sample can be.

My objective is to heat cylindrical steel molds that are 20 cm in diameter, relatively fast and relatively uniform.

So the question is, how can I calculate how big or massive my sample must be for this technology to work?
Is what I'm looking for even feasible?

Answer (score 0):

The essence of induction heating is that an AC current flows through a solenoid (mostly, although there are other ways) which creates an alternate electromagnetic field. Then this electromagnetic field will induce an AC current on the surface of the workpiece which heats it up according to Joule's Law:
\begin{equation*}
E = I^2 R t
\end{equation*}

The specific calculation is extremely complicated due to the different shapes of workpieces but a rule of thumb is the more surface area and the less resistivity, the quicker it will heat up as long as the workpiece is within the effective electromagnetic field generated by the AC solenoid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).